# Using variables in Nginx rewrite rules

Tags: variables, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to map clean URLs to controllers of the same name. I'd like to just use a variable so that my config file doesn't become cluttered. I tried this:

```
location ^~ /$1 {
  rewrite ^ /controllers/$1.php last;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /controllers/$1.php last;
}
```

As the [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) shows